# Mathematics formulae can't be compiled

Tags: beamer

I have this code for my presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp 1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=blue! 25}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\mode<presentation> \title{XY}

\author{XY\\
XY}
\date{}

\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont{title}{shape=\itshape,family=\rmfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\insertframenavigationsymbol
\frametitle{XY}
\begin{align}
\notag
A^{*}_{JY}X\ =\ -Ph(X,\ Y).
\end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am receiving a message: PDFTeXify failed to create a pdf file. Only in case when I use mathematics, otherwise everything is ok.

What could be a problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't leave empty lines inside `align`.

Comment: @HarishKumar I guess the empty lines were there just to show newlines in the message.

Comment: @egreg Yes! Then my question looks confusing.

Comment: @user61285 I copied the code (after my edit to remove the blank lines) and it compiles on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) say, the error was do to the blank line inside the `align` environment.

Here is a MWE of how you can do it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern} % avoid warnings when using beamer

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
  A_{JY}^{\ast}X = -Ph(X,Y).
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

Notice that I have cleaned up the code somewhat and added the [`lmodern`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lm) package to avoid warnings.

**Update**

Notice that in case `Ph` is an operator, you should do as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern} % avoid warnings when using beamer
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ph}{Ph}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
  A_{JY}^{\ast}X = -\Ph(X,Y).
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]